# Qt delegate display text rendered while editor is active

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I implemented a unit text box capable of doing conversions when a different unit is selected. This was done by sticking a QLineEdit and QLabel together using a QHBoxLayout.

[image]

```
class LengthTextBox::Impl
{
    public:
        Impl() :
            lblUnit(new QLabel()),
            txtValue(new QLineEdit()),
            menuLength(new LengthMenu(lblUnit)),
            precision(2),
            unit(units::Length::Meters)
        {
        }

        QLabel* lblUnit;
        QLineEdit* txtValue;
        LengthMenu* menuLength;

        int precision;

        units::Length unit;
};

LengthTextBox::LengthTextBox(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent),
    pimpl()
{
    const auto hLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);

    // Adjust spacing for better fit within tables.
    const auto spacing = 2;
    auto margins = hLayout->contentsMargins();
    margins.setTop(0);
    margins.setLeft(spacing);
    margins.setRight(spacing);
    margins.setBottom(0);
    hLayout->setContentsMargins(margins);
    hLayout->setSpacing(spacing);

    this->pimpl->txtValue->setValidator(new QDoubleValidator());

    // Install an event filter to capture focus out events.
    this->pimpl->txtValue->installEventFilter(this);

    hLayout->addWidget(this->pimpl->txtValue);
    hLayout->addWidget(this->pimpl->lblUnit);

    // Since we're building on top of a QWidget, set up the focus policies to still focus on the text box.
    this->setFocusProxy(this->pimpl->txtValue);
    this->pimpl->txtValue->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    this->pimpl->lblUnit->setFocusPolicy(Qt::ClickFocus);

    // Connect signals for switching between units.
    this->connect(this->pimpl->lblUnit, &QLabel::linkActivated, this, &LengthTextBox::unitSelectorClicked);
    this->connect(this->pimpl->menuLength, &LengthMenu::unitChanged, this, &LengthTextBox::setUnit);

    // Forward the line edit signals.
    this->connect(this->pimpl->txtValue, &QLineEdit::editingFinished, this, &LengthTextBox::editingFinished);
    this->connect(this->pimpl->txtValue, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, this, &LengthTextBox::returnPressed);
    this->connect(this->pimpl->txtValue, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &LengthTextBox::textChanged);
    this->connect(this->pimpl->txtValue, &QLineEdit::textEdited, this, &LengthTextBox::textEdited);

    this->setUnit(this->pimpl->unit);
}

LengthTextBox::~LengthTextBox()
{
}

void LengthTextBox::setPrecision(int x)
{
    this->pimpl->precision = x;
}

int LengthTextBox::getPrecision() const
{
    return this->pimpl->precision;
}

void LengthTextBox::setUnit(const units::Length& x)
{
    const auto value = this->getValue();
    this->setValue(units::Convert(value, this->pimpl->unit, x));

    // Use HTML to render the text as a link. This will lead to the linkActivated signal when clicked.
    const QString link = "<b><a href='#'>" + QString::fromStdString(units::GetSymbol(x)) + "</a></b>";
    this->pimpl->lblUnit->setText(link);

    this->pimpl->txtValue->setFocus(Qt::FocusReason::OtherFocusReason);
    this->pimpl->txtValue->selectAll();

    this->pimpl->unit = x;
    this->unitChanged(this->pimpl->unit);
}

units::Length LengthTextBox::getUnit() const
{
    return this->pimpl->unit;
}

void LengthTextBox::setValue(double x, const units::Length& fromUnit)
{
    if(fromUnit != units::Length::Unknown)
    {
        x = units::Convert(x, fromUnit, this->pimpl->unit);
    }

    this->pimpl->txtValue->setText(QString::number(x, 'f', this->pimpl->precision));
}

double LengthTextBox::getValue(const units::Length& toUnit) const
{
    auto value = this->pimpl->txtValue->text().toDouble();

    if(toUnit != units::Length::Unknown)
    {
        value = units::Convert(value, this->pimpl->unit, toUnit);
    }

    return value;
}

std::string LengthTextBox::getFormattedText() const
{
    return this->pimpl->txtValue->text().toStdString() + " " + units::GetSymbol(this->pimpl->unit);
}

void LengthTextBox::unitSelectorClicked()
{
    this->pimpl->menuLength->popup(QCursor::pos());
}

bool LengthTextBox::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* x)
{
    // Watch for a focus out event on the text box inorder to send a lost focus signal.
    if(this->pimpl->txtValue == obj)
    {
        if(x->type() == QEvent::FocusOut && this->pimpl->lblUnit->hasFocus() == false)
        {
            this->lostFocus();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, x);
}
```

Next, I derived a QStyledItemDelegate so that I could use this text box in my own QTableView.
[image]

If you looks very closely, you'll see that when the editor is active on this delegate, that the letter 'm' is rendered behind the hyperlink 'm'.

```
class LengthTextBoxDelegate::Impl
{
    public:
        Impl(int precision) :
            txtLength(std::make_unique<LengthTextBox>())
        {
            this->txtLength->setPrecision(precision);
        }

        // By using a length text box to manage current selected unit, all conversion logic remains in one place.
        std::unique_ptr<LengthTextBox> txtLength;
};

LengthTextBoxDelegate::LengthTextBoxDelegate(int precision, QWidget* parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent),
    pimpl(precision)
{
}

LengthTextBoxDelegate::~LengthTextBoxDelegate()
{
}

QString LengthTextBoxDelegate::displayText(const QVariant& value, const QLocale&) const
{
    this->pimpl->txtLength->setValue(value.toDouble(), Length::Meters);
    return QString::fromStdString(this->pimpl->txtLength->getText()) + " " + QString::fromStdString(GetSymbol(this->pimpl->txtLength->getSelectedUnit()));
}

QWidget* LengthTextBoxDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem&, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    const auto txtLength = new LengthTextBox(parent);
    txtLength->setValue(index.data().toDouble());
    txtLength->setSelectedUnit(this->pimpl->txtLength->getSelectedUnit());
    txtLength->setPrecision(this->pimpl->txtLength->getPrecision());

    // AMS // This is kind of a hack. For some reason, the ::displayText() that is rendered when no editor is created, was getting rendered
    // behind the editor widget and was appearing through as if the text box was transparent.
    // By setting the background color white, we get a nice aesthetic that matches the table views that use this delegate.
    // In addition, it covers up the text that was appearing behind the widget.
    auto p = txtLength->palette();
    p.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::white);
    txtLength->setPalette(p);
    //txtLength->setAutoFillBackground(true);

    // Track the current unit so that its symbol can be rendered when ::displayText() is called.
    this->connect(txtLength, &LengthTextBox::unitChanged, this, &LengthTextBoxDelegate::unitChanged);
    this->connect(txtLength, &LengthTextBox::returnPressed, this, &LengthTextBoxDelegate::commitAndCloseEditor);
    this->connect(txtLength, &LengthTextBox::lostFocus, this, &LengthTextBoxDelegate::commitAndCloseEditor);

    return txtLength;
}

void LengthTextBoxDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget* editor, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    const auto txtLength = qobject_cast<LengthTextBox*>(editor);
    assert(txtLength != nullptr);

    txtLength->setValue(index.data().toDouble(), Length::Meters);
}

void LengthTextBoxDelegate::setModelData(QWidget* editor, QAbstractItemModel* model, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    const auto txtLength = qobject_cast<LengthTextBox*>(editor);
    assert(txtLength != nullptr);

    model->setData(index, txtLength->getValue(Length::Meters));
}

void LengthTextBoxDelegate::unitChanged(const hive::math::units::Length& x)
{
    this->pimpl->txtLength->setSelectedUnit(x);
}

void LengthTextBoxDelegate::commitAndCloseEditor()
{
    const auto txtLength = qobject_cast<LengthTextBox*>(this->sender());
    this->commitData(txtLength);
    this->closeEditor(txtLength);
}
```

So far the only solution I've come up with is to set the background color on my editor widget. This feels hackish, there must be something else I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent the Qt::DisplayRole text from being rendered while my editor is active?

Comment: What class is actually `LengthTextBox` derived from?

Comment: I edited my post, it derives from QWidget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **fill the background before painting your editor widget**. `QWidget`'s [`autoFillBackground`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop) property controls this behavior, since it is set to `false` by default, Your editor widget gets painted over the `QTableView` .

You just need to set the property on the editor in `createEditor()` before returning it:

```
txtLength->setAutoFillBackground(true);
```

The color of the background is specified using [`setBackgroundRole()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setBackgroundRole), which inherits the parent's background by default (that is [`QPalette::Base`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum) if the parent is a `QTableView`). So, you'll get white background for the editor, You may want to specify the `QPalette::Window` color role instead:

```
txtLength->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::Window);
```